# WebRTC sometimes does not work on local network

Tags: webrtc

I am currently developing a tool that facilitates file transfers between devices on local networks. This tool closely resembles [ShareDrop.io](https://sharedrop.io/).

However, I've encountered intermittent issues. Sometimes, the peer connection fails on certain Wi-Fi networks, whereas on other days, it functions properly.

In my attempts to debug this issue, I've found that I occasionally receive a response code 701 from the STUN servers.

Interestingly, when this error occurs, ShareDrop.io also fails to work as expected aswell.

I assume that sometimes some firewall configuration changes on the local network in the router, and I don't have TURN servers so that's why the connection fails? and if yes, why would the firewall behave diffrently everytime?

Here are the logs from my webrtc-internal:

```
ICE connection state: new => checking => disconnected
Connection state: new => connecting => failed => closed
Signaling state: new => have-local-offer => stable
ICE Candidate pair: (not connected)
ICE candidate grid
Time    Event
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
createDataChannel
label: e8cfa3fa6fb124e254d8c811858b2aa5ad9f05e0, reliable: false
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   negotiationneeded
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
createOffer
options: {offerToReceiveVideo: -1, offerToReceiveAudio: -1, voiceActivityDetection: true, iceRestart: false}
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
createOfferOnSuccess (type: "offer", 2 sections)
Copy description to clipboard
v=0 (6 more lines)
o=- 8711689258386202606 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel (9 more lines) mid=0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:uDtK
a=ice-pwd:EHcAqT9C8h6saAXg9fJICtIs
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
setLocalDescription (munged) (type: "offer", 2 sections)
Copy description to clipboard
v=0 (6 more lines)
o=- 8711689258386202606 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel (8 more lines) mid=0
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:uDtK
a=ice-pwd:EHcAqT9C8h6saAXg9fJICtIs
a=fingerprint:sha-256 F6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   setLocalDescriptionOnSuccess
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
signalingstatechange
have-local-offer
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icegatheringstatechange
gathering
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: host)
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:645871773 1 udp 2113937151 9f40d252-3735-454d-84f0-f2d9c1c08ed5.local 61420 typ host generation 0 ufrag uDtK network-cost 999
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icecandidate(sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, type: srflx)
sdpMid: 0, sdpMLineIndex: 0, candidate: candidate:3735013259 1 udp 1677729535 93.172.234.166 61420 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 ufrag uDtK network-cost 999
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icecandidateerror
url: stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
address: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]
port: 61421
host_candidate: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]:61421
error_text: STUN host lookup received error.
error_code: 701
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icecandidateerror
url: stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478
address: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]
port: 61421
host_candidate: [0:0:0:x:x:x:x:x]:61421
error_text: STUN host lookup received error.
error_code: 701
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
icegatheringstatechange
complete
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
setRemoteDescription (type: "answer", 2 sections)
Copy description to clipboard
v=0 (6 more lines)
o=- 5874129012365131719 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 60791 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel (11 more lines) mid=0
c=IN IP4 93.172.234.166
a=candidate:4219463918 1 udp 2122260223 b1564d21-6f70-48e0-ba8d-5035df11d528.local 60791 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:2050485850 1 udp 1686052607 93.172.234.166 60791 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=candidate:3053196318 1 tcp 1518280447 b1564d21-6f70-48e0-ba8d-5035df11d528.local 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 10
a=ice-ufrag:msZT
a=ice-pwd:KenL2JJs3eMrbF4USIzafD5F
a=fingerprint:sha-256 2F:F2:D0:50:3A:DD:0E:AC:0D:A1:22:68:D8:75:B1:54:13:97:B6:DE:B4:F4:F3:49:52:35:B9:F4:4B:AF:8F:E4
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
iceconnectionstatechange
checking
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   setRemoteDescriptionOnSuccess
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
signalingstatechange
stable
7/31/2023, 2:42:05 AM   
connectionstatechange
connecting
7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM   
iceconnectionstatechange
disconnected
7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM   
connectionstatechange
failed
7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM   close
7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM   
connectionstatechange
closed
Stats Tables
Filter statistics by type including 
separate multiple values by `,`
media-playout (kind=audio, id=AP)
certificate (id=CFF6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8)
Statistics CFF6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
fingerprint F6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8
fingerprintAlgorithm    sha-256
base64Certificate   MIIBFTCBvaADAgECAgkA9WD91eIP72wwCgYIKoZIzj0EAwIwETEPMA0GA1UEAwwGV2ViUlRDMB4XDTIzMDcyOTIzNDIwNVoXDTIzMDgyOTIzNDIwNVowETEPMA0GA1UEAwwGV2ViUlRDMFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAEErV9/mBOv2M5hLz5FaerQMPcwL/Hp9ew0FOzbSVvFIVu6RO46u4Ab4qB8np5EGyYh4af7JXIcH7LcRU/f33oQzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNHADBEAiBy2aaWMUsK/kj34RJPGMFhmxui+onSsQsS6qVjmF5Q0AIgAsEN/3affdLj/WVlR9WBDdcsL6WQdEiRyBRB3Bi1njU=
candidate-pair (state=in-progress, id=CPaCcUGVcg_LI/qbZhE)
Statistics CPaCcUGVcg_LI/qbZhE
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
localCandidateId    IaCcUGVcg
remoteCandidateId   ILI/qbZhE
state   in-progress
priority    7241540810628414975
nominated   false
writable    false
packetsSent 0
[packetsSent/s] 0
packetsReceived 0
[packetsReceived/s] 0
bytesSent   0
[bytesSent_in_bits/s]   0
bytesReceived   0
[bytesReceived_in_bits/s]   0
totalRoundTripTime  0
[totalRoundTripTime/responsesReceived]  0
requestsReceived    0
requestsSent    224
responsesReceived   0
responsesSent   0
consentRequestsSent 0
packetsDiscardedOnSend  0
bytesDiscardedOnSend    0
data-channel (id=D1)
Statistics D1
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
label   e8cfa3fa6fb124e254d8c811858b2aa5ad9f05e0
protocol    
dataChannelIdentifier   1
state   connecting
messagesSent    0
[messagesSent/s]    0
bytesSent   0
[bytesSent_in_bits/s]   0
messagesReceived    0
[messagesReceived/s]    0
bytesReceived   0
[bytesReceived_in_bits/s]   0
local-candidate (candidateType=host, tcpType=active, id=I1DA3kZ9R)
Statistics I1DA3kZ9R
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    false
networkType unknown
ip  
address 
port    9
protocol    tcp
candidateType   host
priority    1509957375
foundation  1301002440
usernameFragment    uDtK
tcpType active
vpn*    false
networkAdapterType* any
local-candidate (candidateType=srflx, id=I8IowUIqK)
Statistics I8IowUIqK
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    false
networkType unknown
ip  93.172.234.166
address 93.172.234.166
port    61420
protocol    udp
candidateType   srflx
priority    1677729535
url stun:stun.l.google.com:19302
foundation  3735013259
usernameFragment    uDtK
vpn*    false
networkAdapterType* any
remote-candidate (candidateType=srflx, id=ILI/qbZhE)
Statistics ILI/qbZhE
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    true
ip  93.172.234.166
address 93.172.234.166
port    60791
protocol    udp
candidateType   srflx
priority    1686052607
foundation  2050485850
usernameFragment    msZT
local-candidate (candidateType=host, id=IN4TTfrYE)
Statistics IN4TTfrYE
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    false
networkType unknown
ip  
address 
port    61421
protocol    udp
candidateType   host
priority    2113929727
foundation  2152007095
usernameFragment    uDtK
vpn*    false
networkAdapterType* any
local-candidate (candidateType=host, id=IaCcUGVcg)
Statistics IaCcUGVcg
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    false
networkType unknown
ip  
address 
port    61420
protocol    udp
candidateType   host
priority    2113937151
foundation  645871773
usernameFragment    uDtK
vpn*    false
networkAdapterType* any
local-candidate (candidateType=host, tcpType=active, id=IejdqK/75)
Statistics IejdqK/75
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
transportId T01
isRemote    false
networkType unknown
ip  
address 
port    9
protocol    tcp
candidateType   host
priority    1509949951
foundation  4270516015
usernameFragment    uDtK
tcpType active
vpn*    false
networkAdapterType* any
peer-connection (id=P)
Statistics P
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:43:36 AM
dataChannelsOpened  0
dataChannelsClosed  0
transport (iceState=checking, dtlsState=new, id=T01)
Statistics T01
timestamp   7/31/2023, 2:42:20 AM
bytesSent   0
[bytesSent_in_bits/s]   0
packetsSent 0
[packetsSent/s] 0
bytesReceived   0
[bytesReceived_in_bits/s]   0
packetsReceived 0
[packetsReceived/s] 0
dtlsState   new
localCertificateId  CFF6:6D:8A:79:5D:CB:60:DC:95:7C:F3:37:04:99:F2:07:F0:38:9A:17:09:CB:37:1F:AD:48:B4:6A:87:A5:EF:D8
dtlsRole    server
selectedCandidatePairChanges    0
iceRole controlling
iceLocalUsernameFragment    uDtK
iceState    checking
```

Comment: For testing purposes, you can use the TURN server specified in the following web page:
https://dev.to/aprogrammer22/list-of-free-stun-and-turn-servers-open-relay-project-3a70

Comment: But I do not need TURN servers for my tool, the purpose is to work on local network for fast transferring, I do not allow open internet transfers, therefore making it work with TURN servers or STUN is pointless, the devices are on local network. Or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: Unless you have a STUN/TURN server in your local network, you need to access the internet to communicate with the STUN/TURN. The use of the TURN server gives you another way to solve the problem.

Comment: The description for error code 701 as below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/icecandidateerror_event

Comment: But NAT traversal isn't typically needed as devices on local network can usually communicate with each other directly without the need for something like a STUN server, that's what confusing me in this situation

Comment: It is because the STUN server is outside of your local network. It may return the connection candidate from the internet view, not the intranet view. So the connection may be broken by your firewall. If you want to have a complete intranet connection, you have better set up a STUN/TURN in your local network.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @TheKNVB the issue is ESET antivirus that my company computer has installed, im 90% sure that's the issue because my code works perfectly on other devices. I saw that the port is unreachable via Wireshark and ESET is the only one that may block it, cause the firewall is fine both on windows and the router, and since I don't use TURN servers it can't establish any connection. Maybe it explains why linkedin chat works with webrtc for me on this PC because it uses TURN in worst case

Comment: If ESET blocks UDP that would be an explanation. The only mention of it in the WebRTC context is a decade old: https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/MV9c-qR0iWU/m/ttj_J9M7gzoJ